# CSS Animation for Button Text

Tags: css

I need to do some animation for button. The structure of button is:

```
<button>
    <img>
    MyButtonText
</button>
```

The animation should work like this: when the button appears on the page the button image should appear without animation, and the button text should appear smoothly from left to right.

I should do it with CSS.

I tried to add the folowing animation css class:

```
.my-anim{
    animation: btnslide .5s ease-out;
}
    .my-anim::before {
        content: '';
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    }

@keyframes btnslide {
    0%,25% {
        transform: translateX(-120%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Though it does not work the way I want.

EDIT

I found another solution but still it doesn not work correctly:

```css
.myanim {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: animslide 1s ease;
}
    .myanim::before{
        width: 0%;
    }
    
@keyframes animslide {
    from {
        width: 0%;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<button>
<img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/20190530/ourmid/pngtree-correct-icon-image_1267804.jpg" height="20">
<span class="myanim">Hi there</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I didn’t understand why you are moving stuff in the y direction. Is the text to end up to the right of the img (assuming there is room)?

Comment: The text should be shown after the image, so when the button appears, text should be located after the image and animated from left to right

Comment: Does ‘after’ mean it sits to the right of the img or below it?

Comment: It means the text sits on the right side of the image

Comment: It is unclear to me exactly what you want. Does animating `max-width` rather than `width` improve it? I wonder if rather than animating the text you should be animating the `button` width to reveal the text.

Comment: Max-width helped with the hopping, thank you. Yes, adding animation to the button itself can be the solution, but the problem is that the image could have different sizes and I do not know how to calculate its width

Comment: Do you want the button to start off at its full width (albeit without showing full text) or do you want the button to grow as the text gradually gets shown?

Comment: I want the second option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the button to grow and reveal the text. You can achieve this using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout) layout for the button and animating the width of the `.myanim` grid item from `0fr` (fractional units) to `1fr`

```css
.myanim {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

@keyframes animslide {
  from {
    grid-template-columns: 0fr 0fr;
  }
  to {
    grid-template-columns: 0fr 1fr;
  }
}

button {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0fr 1fr;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  animation: animslide 1s ease;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button>
<img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/20190530/ourmid/pngtree-correct-icon-image_1267804.jpg" height="20">
<span class="myanim">Hi there</span>
</button>

<!-- second example to show how it copes with different sized image and text -->

<button>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/40/40" width="40">
<span class="myanim">I dont mind what size things are!</span>
</button>
```

Comment: B E A U T I F U L !!!!
Thank you!